How to write a pandoc lua filter function that replaces (wraps) Paragraphs with a custom-style div? Filter only for AST top-level Para blocks?
I managed to write this filter to replace Markdown Blockquote environments with a div for export to a Word template that uses special styles (that are also named differently than the default styles pandoc uses). I have no experience programming, but I worked out how to accomplish this:
function BlockQuote(elem)
  return pandoc.Div (elem.content, {["custom-style"] = "Displayed quotation"})
end

The next task is to write a similar function to turn every Paragraph into a special div environment (wrap it in a div in the AST), and also every First Paragraph (At the beginning of a section or after a block quote.)
However, the "Para" element in the AST is present within other element I don't want to change. In other words, I only want to change the top-level Paras, not the ones within other elements (such as blockquote). How can I test for the level where the element is in the tree? Or is there a better way?
And how can I test for whether a paragraph comes after a paragraph, a heading, or a blockquote?
I also have general beginner questions about the syntax, and would like to see if I get it. "elem" is a variable that holds the content of the BlockQuote element. That content is a "block" (as opposed to an inline element), or in Lua terms, a table (but everything is a table in Lua?).
I am trying to understand the syntax of accessing the content via elem.content. I think what's after the dot is a field in the table? Or in this case the whole table? For headers, there would be the expression elem.level to manipulate the level of the heading.
What is the meaning of this syntax: variable_name.field_name (elem.content)? Where can I look up what fields are available?
And where can I find the most beginner-friendly Lua tutorial, ideally with a focus on Pandoc?
I know these are many questions, but the first one is the most important (actual one). Any help or input is greatly appreciated!
I don't even know where to begin.

A good place for general support is over at the pandoc Discussions board on GitHub.
